# How can I remove the pop up information window for Python code in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[weird pop up window with Python code in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7iV.png)

I am new to learning Python and use VS Code to do so. Everything works fine but I get these weird information pop up windows when I type some code. I have no idea what they are and the information shown makes no sense to me.
I already tried turning of the suggestions in the preferences but it didn't change anything.
Can I remove this and if so: How should I do this?

Comment: have you ever looked at the definition of the `print` function, that is what the popup shows, the arguments and there type, `print` can do a whole lot more then printing strings

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, just open up settings with ⌘+, and add this:

```
{
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to turn off IntelliSense completely like the above answer. After all, IntelliSense can make our work more convenient in use. All we have to do is turn off the parameterInfo. You can add the following contents to the setting.json

```
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
},
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
```